# GUI opens when i double cklick the .py file, but doesn't when i run it in pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myLabel = Label(root, text='Hello World!')

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When i try to run it with the play button in pycharm nothing happens, but when i copy it into the Python Console it opens a GUI
Also works if i double cklick the file.

Why is nothing happening if i try to run it with the button ?

i've copied this code from a YT tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV

Answer (score 0):

I have the tendency to just, right click the file on PyCharm and click on the `run` option.
Because, when you directly click on the run button, it plays all your files onpened on Pycharm, so if you have more than one file it's not great...

Comment: Allright, works better. Thanks